# Nested reducers

Tags: javascript, redux, reducers

To learn Redux, I am starting a simplistic web application.

If there is an "authentification" action validating username and password. I then want a "login" or "fail" action to be called. I can not figure out how.
I can call the authentification step, but the nested/following call are not executed.

How is it possible to call a function from within another function? (That's how frustrating my problem boils down ^^)

My code looks like the following:

```
function authenticateClient(state, client){
    if (client.password === 'perfectsec')
        return dispatch(Actions.connectClient(client));
    else
        return dispatch(Actions.refuseClient(client));
}
```

**Calling dispatch in a reducer is incorrect. The simplest would be to call directly the functions `connectClient(state, client)` or `refuseClient(state, client)`. But then this step does not go through the redux flow.**

---

context code:

```
/* actions.js */

export function authenticateClient(client) {
  return { type: Types.authenticateClient, client };
}

export function connectClient(client, isNew) {
  return { type: Types.connectClient, client, isNew };
}

export function refuseClient(client) {
  return { type: Types.refuseClient, client };
}


/* main.js */

/* reducer */
const reducer = (state = loadState(), action) => {
  console.log(chalk.red(`*${action.type}*`));
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.Types.authenticateClient:
      return authenticateClient(state, action);
    case Actions.Types.connectClient:
      return connectClient(state, action);
    case Actions.Types.refuseClient:
      return refuseClient(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


/* store */
store = createStore(reducer);


/* app */
store.dispatch(Actions.authenticateClient({username, password}));
```

Comment: I'm not 100% able to follow your code, so just to clarify - you're not trying to dispatch actions from within the reducers, are you? Because that's the one place you're 100% _never_ supposed to dispatch actions.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. And I noticed that this is incorrect. But I do not understand how to achieve my goal. I added a paragraph, trying to clarify.

Comment: If you need to dispatch actions conditionally, this logic should most likely be in another action creator (e.g. `Actions.connectClientIfValid(client)`) - if the input is valid, return the result of `Actions.connectClient(client)`, if not, return the result of `Actions.refuseClient(client)`. You can then dispatch whatever gets returned. All your reducer should ever do is `state + action = newState` - it should never have side effects on the rest of your application.

Comment: That said, it gets a little more complex if you need to dispatch multiple actions as a result of one action creator being called - I'd really recommend reading the tutorial on the Redux website and following through the screencasts that the author made, as it covers all of this stuff and the guy explains it better than I probably can :)

Comment: And where should the little piece of logic `IF valid THEN connect ELSE refuse` be?
I read and watch all of that 3 months ago and am now giving it a try, maybe I should repeat. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Based on your current structure, `actions.js` would probably be the logical place. Add another function like `export function connectClientIfValid(client)`, then just return from that the result of the other action creators based on whether or not it's valid. Key thing here is, you don't need to actually dispatch the action in this function - if all it does is conditionally return an action, you can use it just like any other action creator - `dispatch(connectClientIfValid(client))`.

Comment: Posted a more in-depth description with examples as an answer - hopefully it'll help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducers should never dispatch actions, or do anything else that has side effects. All a reducer should ever be is a pure function of state and actions (effectively `state + action = newState`) - the entire Redux library is built around this assumption, and I believe it's specifically designed to throw an error if you try to call dispatch inside a reducer.

The best way to go about conditionally dispatching an action is to create a new 'action creator' - you have a few of these in your application already:

```
export function authenticateClient(client) {
  return { type: Types.authenticateClient, client };
}

export function connectClient(client, isNew) {
  return { type: Types.connectClient, client, isNew };
}

export function refuseClient(client) {
  return { type: Types.refuseClient, client };
}
```

Note that standard action creators don't dispatch the action themselves. They're just functions that *return* an action, which you can dispatch yourself at some point (this is handy if you want to create an action and hold on to it for a little while before actually sending it off). The waters get muddied somewhat once you start writing async action creators, but that's not really in the scope of your problem so I'll skip over it for now (I recommend reading the Async section of the documentation, though! You can do some really cool things once you get your head around it).

What you're trying to express here is a function that says, 'if a condition is true, give me a `connectClient` action, if not, give me a `refuseClient` action'. We already know that a function that gives you an action is an action creator, which leads us to the main point of this answer: **action creators can have logic**. While 90% of them will just take in data and immediately return an object, this isn't the only form they can take. Here's an example of how this functionality could be represented:

```
export function connectClientIfValid(client) {
  if (client.valid === true) {
    return connectClient(client);
  }
  else {
    return refuseClient(client);
  }
}
```

Again, nothing actually gets dispatched from this function - it just returns an action, which you can dispatch at your leisure, like so:

```
dispatch(connectClientIfValid(client));
```

Your logic runs, and the appropriate action gets dispatched, without having to compromise the pure/synchronous nature of your reducer. All your reducer has to do is read the actions as they come in, and update the state appropriately - it doesn't have to care about the logic that caused the actions to happen.

Comment: Thank you again for your patience. Time will tell if I really grasp it. As you point out, the difference between a reducer and an action creator is important to get straight.
What I was trying to do is simply a "sub reducer". My authenticateClient is a reducer. I could use [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) for this use case.